# iphone app  build by mosync framework

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ios4

I created project in mosync by choosing new project and project templete as MOsync MAUI project and just wrote hello world and build the project in Mosync editor and it ran succesfully and hello world was seen in emulator of Mosync.
After that i selected iphone in device family and build project for iphone and then go to the build folder whr xcode project was generated and i ran this xcode project and its crash with no error but 24 warnings .most of warnings are like -unused variable r15,unused variable r14 and 1 more important warning was in line this:-

```
    mosyncView = [[MoSyncView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

//waring is:-reciever MoSyncView is forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist.
```

can any 1 please solve this thing!!!!thanx in advance and thanx for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this stuff is fixed so get the new version at:

http://www.mosync.com/documentation/manualpages/whats-new-mosync-26-pyramid

Hope this helps,

Tony

PS. I especially love the HTML integration, the ability to create and call native code, it both directions, cool :) I'm really excited about the potential of HTML UI.